# Simplifying the difference quotient $\frac{(x + h)^3 - x^3}{h}$.

Tags: calculus, functions, polynomials

For the function $f(x) = x^3$, I have the difference quotient:

> $$
> \frac{(x + h)^3 - x^3}{h}
> $$

I tried changing the $(x + h)^3$ to $(x + h)(x^2 - xh + h^2)$ that I know to see if I could get things to cancel but still couldn't get it worked out.

It's supposed to be $3x^2 + 3xh + h^2$. I got the $3xh$ and the $2x$ but not the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After expanding everything out, we want to factor out an $h$ so that the $h$'s cancel:
\begin{align*}
(x + h)^3 - x^3
&= (x^3 + 3hx^2 + 3h^2x + h^3) - x^3 \\
&= 3hx^2 + 3h^2x + h^3 \\
&= h(3x^2 + 3hx + h^2)
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks. Had never seen that way of expanding the cubes before.